# set active class to element based on child elements href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, navigation

I have written code for navigation. I want to check which class is active, according to that it should set color blue for that respective tab

**My Code**

```js
$(function() {
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $("#tslcNav ul li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
      $(this).addClass("active");
  })
});
```

```css
.tslcNav li:hover,
.tslcNav li.active,
.tslcNav li.active {
  background: none;
  border-color: #009FD6;
  color: #009FD6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tslcNav" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="manage.html">Manage </a></li>
      <li><a href="welcome.html">welcome/a></li>
          <li><a href="security.html">Security </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are placing the active on the a element, not the list
Change your javascript code to this:

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    $(".tslcNav ul li a").each(function(){
         if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
         $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    })
});
```

Comment: Still it is not displaying properly.As it should set the tab in blue color

Comment: Edited the answer, your jquery selector has #tslcNav, while your html is using a class.

Comment: If I want to access it it in jsp instead of html then what changes I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because you are adding class active to anchor element. And your selector targets li elements with class active. Hence you need to add class active to parent li, instead of adding it to anchor element. you can use `.closest()` or `.parent()` here:

```
 $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
```